Grid Counting Problem, Cannot Cross y=x
I'm attempting the following question:
How many paths are there where you can only move up or right one unit at each step that go from (0, 0) to (5, 3) without crossing the line y = x? You are allowed to touch it.
Without considering y=x, we would have 56 ways to reach (5,3). How do I frame this question to approach an answer?

Do this help? Or this? Or this? Keywords that are relevant here: Betrand's ballot problem/theorem, reflection principle, Catalan numbers.

Got it. I'll try applying these. Thanks!

If I don't have a calculation error if 5=n+1,3=n-1 then in general the answer is:
(2n-1 choose n) - (2n-1 choose n-3).

@SammyBlack You might mention the reflection principle in your comment is not this one.

Let $n=4$ and solve the general case of $(n+1, n-1)$ instead of $(5,3)$.
As in the catalan proof reflect paths across $y=x-1$.
You will get exactly all paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ that begin with a right step, except for those who exceed the reflection of $y=x$ which is $y=x-2$ i.e those who intersect with $y=x-3$. Call these paths bad.
There are ${2n-1 \choose n}$ non-bad paths.
Reflect accrose $y=x-3$ and you will see every bad path correspond to a normal path starting with a right step from $(0,0)$ to $(n+3,n-3)$. Hence there are ${2n-1 \choose n+3}$ bad paths.
Overall ${2n-1 \choose n}-{2n-1 \choose n+3}$ which is $28$ in case $n=4$ $\blacksquare$

"as in the Catalan proof..." is a little cryptic... for those who don't know well these questions.

Yeah, I tend to forget to refernce things in my proofs... I guess you can just omit this quote :) or read this section
